# Replace image src in javascript

Tags: javascript

In a script, the following line replaces the 3 last caracters from a image filename with nothing:

```
nIMG.setAttribute('src',isImg.replace(/_40\./, '.'));
```

Example: abc_40.jpg = abc.jpg

Where can I change this line so I can replace _40 with _200 ?

Thanks

Comment: `nIMG.setAttribute('src',isImg.replace(/_40/, '_200'));`

Comment: nIMG.setAttribute('src',isImg.replace(/_40\./, '_200.'));

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Thanks, what was the dot there for?

Comment: I'm guessing the . is there to make sure it's the last characters of the image. In case it also has _40 elsewhere in the name

Comment: you were raplacing "_40." with ".", in case that in name was something like "image_40_long_40.jpg"

Comment: why not just assign directly to the  *src* the property? Like `nImg.src= isImg.replace(/_40/, '_200');`

Comment: Thanks guys, i realize its a dumb question, but I have very limited knowledge in java. Thanks for the help.

Comment: *why not just assign to the src the property?* thats just difference between JS/JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the replace arg : `/_40\./, '_200.'`

Comment: That means lookup and find for a substring equals to `_40.`, and replace it with `_400.`, so that a string equals to `blahblah_40.foo` will be replaced by `blahblah_200.foo`.